# open android device monitor error

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot open android device monitor in android studio to see  the database
I saw the solutions in similar problems on this website , but doesn't working till now

[image]

Comment: **I saw the solutions in similar problems on this website** - such as?

Comment: I tried the suggested solutions , but unfortunately nothing worked with me

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by download Java SE Runtime Environment 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

and delete previous version

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, even i had the same jre. However, the device monitor can be opened in another way in Android Studio 3.1 version.

**View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer**

Device File Explorer work same as a Android Device Monitor

Note: Each device can be attached to only one debugger process at a time. So, for example, if you are using Android Studio to debug your app on a device, you need to disconnect the Android Studio debugger from the device before you attach a debugger process from the Android Device Monitor.